# Sidekiq Active job function perform_later not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob

so this is my first time working with an active job. I chose the sidekiq adapter , and currently i am having this issue.
[image: mypage]

I want to queue up my jobs to be run one at a time, so i figure using perform_later would be the way to go. However, it seems that the ActiveJob function of rails is not even working.

I am also currently following this tutorial as well to setup my rails's active job
[the video tut](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GBEDvF1_8B8)

Answer (score 0):

You should set sidekiq as default queue adapter in application.rb

```
# config/application.rb
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Be sure to have the adapter's gem in your Gemfile
    # and follow the adapter's specific installation
    # and deployment instructions.
    config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
  end
end
```